# Bootstrap modal event.relatedTarget doesn't work inside dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

I have a foreach loop which goes trough a list of rules with each rule having a bootstrap dropdown to edit the rule. The dropdown link should open a modal, which it does.

The problem is that the event.relatedTarget always has the data from the first dropdown item instead of the actual dropdown item that has been clicked. If I remove the dropdown and just use normal links everything works fine how it should.

What am I doing wrong here?

**The loop with dropdown:**

```
@foreach( $rules as $rule )
    <a href="#" OnClick="event.preventDefault();" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink{{ $rule->id }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-offset="-1,8">{{ $rule->name }} <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a><br />

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink{{ $rule->id }}">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" OnClick="event.preventDefault();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRule" data-id="{{ $rule->id }}" data-name="{{ $rule->name }}">Edit rule</a></li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

**The modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editRule" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editRuleCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content text-white bg-dark">
            <form method="POST" action="#">
                @csrf

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editRuleCenterTitle">Edit Rule</h5>

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="ruleName" class="form-label">Rule name</label>

                            <input id="ruleName" type="text" class="form-control" name="ruleName" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Rule</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The script:**

```
@section( 'scripts' )
<script>
    $( '#editRule' ).on( 'show.bs.modal', function ( event ) {
        console.log( event.relatedTarget );
        var button = $( event.relatedTarget );
        var id = button.data( 'id' );
        var name = button.data( 'name' );
        var modal = $( this );
        modal.find( '.modal-title' ).text( 'Edit rule: ' + name );
        modal.find( '.modal-body input' ).val( name );
    });
</script>
@endsection
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your foreach loop inside a div with class dropdown:

```
@foreach( $rules as $rule )
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" OnClick="event.preventDefault();" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink{{ $rule->id }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-offset="-1,8">{{ $rule->name }} <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a><br />

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink{{ $rule->id }}">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" OnClick="event.preventDefault();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRule" data-id="{{ $rule->id }}" data-name="{{ $rule->name }}">Edit rule</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Wow that worked, thanks! Why does it need to have a div called dropdown around it?

Comment: Because with ut, the bootstrap structure for dropdown somehow breaks.